# How to deploy a react app in production over https?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https, environment-variables, production

I have a React App that works beautifully over HTTPS using a .env.production file containing:

```
HTTPS=true
SSL_CRT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/private/mykey.key
```

the package.json file contains:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",
   "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build"
}
```

when I do:

```
npm start
```

everything works, and I can access my server over HTTPS from anywhere. Now, this is the funny thing, now I do:

```
npm run build:production
```

which also works fine, and I get:

```
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

serve -s build
```

Now, this is what fails:

1) When I use the serve command above, the environment variables in the .env.production file are not picked up! Why?

2) If I pass the environment variables manually as in:

```
HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/private/mykey.key PORT=8580 serve -s build
```

Only the PORT variable seems to be picked up, but the server now runs on HTTP. Any ideas why?!

Comment: react-scripts start starts the *development* server. Never use that for production. To use React in production, build the project and server over a proper web server.

Comment: Where did you find the key? I got one certificate file from the provider. Does the key  the ssh key of your local computer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run `npm start`, a development server is started for you under the hood that is configured to pick up the SSL_CRT_FILE, SSL_KEY_FILE and HTTPS env vars automatically.

`serve` doesn't do that, you need to let it know with these CLI flags:

```
serve -s build --listen 8580 --ssl-cert "/etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt" --ssl-key "/etc/ssl/private/mykey.key"
```

Comment: Quite late but how did you know this? I couldn't find it in the documentation

Comment: @Laif For CRA right here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development#custom-ssl-certificate. For serve you run `serve --help` to get a list of CLI options

Comment: serve documentation is very very bad